# How to split range in groups?

Tags: algorithm, dart

I am writing microservice in Dart.
Service run workers by passing command args to workers like: "app.exe -a=1,2,3,4".
So if `currentlyActiveWorkers` is `4`. Then jobs can be splited to sevaral workers like:

first: `"app.exe -a=1,2,3,4"`

second: `"app.exe -a=5,6,7,8"`

third: `"app.exe -a=9,10,11,12"`

fourth: `"app.exe -a=13,14,15,16"`.

I wrote next prototype:

```
void main() {
  
  int maxWorkers = 16;
  int currentlyActiveWorkers = 2;

  genJobs() {
    int step = 1; 
    int sliceSize = (maxWorkers/currentlyActiveWorkers).round(); 
    var list = [for(var i=step; i<=maxWorkers; i+=1) i];

    for(int i in Iterable<int>.generate(currentlyActiveWorkers))
    {
      print(list.sublist(i * sliceSize, sliceSize * step));
      step++;
    }

  }
  genJobs();
  
}
```

It work fine if `currentlyActiveWorkers` is multiple of 2. It's generate suitable jobs numbers:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

But there is bug if user specify for example `3`. Last number `16` is loosing.
Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

It does not matter for me the number element in every group +- 1 is ok for me.

Comment: Have you tried any debugging yet? What were your findings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rounding logic is ambiguous. Besides, you should handle the last chunk of data in different way:

```
void main() {
  print(genJobs());
}

Map<int, List<int>> genJobs() {
  final activeWorkers = 3;
  final maxJobs = 16;
  final jobs = List<int>.generate(maxJobs, (i) => i + 1);
  final workerCapacity = (jobs.length / activeWorkers).floor();

  var chunks = <int, List<int>>{};
  for (var workerNumber = 0; workerNumber < activeWorkers; workerNumber++) {
    final startIndex = workerNumber * workerCapacity;
    final endIndex = startIndex + workerCapacity;
    final chunk = jobs.sublist(
      startIndex,
      endIndex > jobs.length || workerNumber == activeWorkers - 1
          ? jobs.length
          : endIndex,
    );
    chunks.addAll({workerNumber: chunk});
  }

  return chunks;
}
```

Comment: After long testing I decided to back to your answer. It have only problem on range like: `final jobs = [1,3,4,5,6,7,10,14,17,18,19];`. The last array that it's produce is very big: `{0: [1, 3, 4], 1: [5, 6, 7], 2: [10, 14, 17, 18, 19]}`

Comment: If you have `activeWorkers = 3` then it is the only correct result when `jobs` length is 11, because 11%3 = 2. It means in the last chunk has 2 elements more than other chunks.

Comment: I have found bug in code https://gist.github.com/bubnenkoff/1a4a77f8b90d08437226cbd53db8e38a error: `RangeError (RangeError (start): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..12: 14)`

Comment: If `workerCapacity` depends on length of `jobs`, you should calculate it after removing items from `jobs`. And remember to check whether the boundary conditions are satisfied or not.

Comment: @Owszar it's seem that I am stupid. How to correctly check bounds? `if(workerCapacity == 0) {workerCapacity = jobs.length;}` ?

Comment: It's not so easy. There should be more logic than just cover common boundaries. Check out your gist. I put explanations in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are picking a fixed size for the slices first, even when the number of elements isn't a multiple of the slice count. You're lucky that it rounded down instead of up, otherwise you'd have gotten an index-out-of-range error (try your code with 17 elements and three groups).

First you should figure our what result you *want*. Then you can try coding that.

For something like 22 elements and four groups, you probably want two groups of 6 elements and two groups of 5 elements, not three groups of 6 and one of 4 (since you say +/-1 is OK, not +/- 2).

I would do something like:

```dart
/// Emits the integers from 0 to [elementCount] - 1 in [groupCount] grups.
///
/// The [elementCount] must be greater than zero.
/// The [groupCount] must be in the range 1..[elementCount],
/// meaning that each group will have at least one element, and 
/// each element is in at least one group.
Iterable<List<int>> evenlySpreadGroups(int elementCount, int groupCount) sync* {
  if (elementCount < 1) {
    throw RangeError.range(elementCount, 1, null, "elementCount");
  }
  RangeError.checkValueInInterval(groupCount, 1, elementCount, "groupCount");
  var list = <int>[];
  var groupIndex = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {
    while (i * groupCount >= groupIndex * elementCount) {
      yield list;
      list = [];
      groupIndex += 1;
    }
    list.add(i);
  }   
  yield list;
}
```

(It's written to also work if you allow more groups than elements, any `groupCount` >= 1, you'll just get empty lists in the output which is just rarely useful).

Answer (score 0):

The more solutions the better:

```
import 'package:lists/lists.dart';

void main() {
  final maxPartSize1 = 5;

  final data1 = genData(1, 16);
  print('data: $data1');
  final parts1 = split(data1, maxPartSize1);
  print('parts by $maxPartSize1: $parts1');
  print('=====');

  final maxPartSize2 = 3;

  final data2 = genData(2, 8);
  print('data: $data2');
  final parts2 = split(data2, maxPartSize2);
  print('parts by $maxPartSize2: $parts2');
}

List<int> genData(int start, int length) {
  return List<int>.generate(length, (i) => i + start);
}

Iterable<List<int>> split(List<int> data, int step) sync* {
  final length = data.length;
  for (final i in StepList(0, length - 1, step)) {
    var i2 = i + step;
    if (i2 > length) {
      i2 = length;
    }

    yield data.sublist(i, i2);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
parts by 5: ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16])
=====
data: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
parts by 3: ([2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9])
```

Another way:

```
void main() {
  final maxWorkers1 = 8;
  final datLen1 = 16;
  final data1 = [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];
  print('data: $data1');
  final parts1 = split(data1, maxWorkers1);
  print('$maxWorkers1 workers: $parts1');
  print('=====');

  final maxWorkers2 = 4;
  final datLen2 = 11;
  final data2 = genData(3, datLen2);
  print('data: $data2');
  final parts2 = split(data2, maxWorkers2);
  print('$maxWorkers2 workers: $parts2');

  print('=====');
  final maxWorkers3 = 8;
  final data3 = [7, 8, 3, 4];
  print('data: $data3');
  final parts3 = split(data3, maxWorkers3);
  print('$maxWorkers3 workers: $parts3');
}

List<int> genData(int start, int length) {
  return List<int>.generate(length, (i) => i + start);
}

Iterable<List<int>> split(List<int> data, int divider) sync* {
  if (divider <= 0) {
    throw RangeError.value(divider, 'divider', 'Must be greater than 0');
  }

  if (data.isEmpty) {
    // Nothing to do
    return;
  }

  final length = data.length;
  divider = divider > length ? length : divider;
  var partSize = length ~/ divider;
  if (length != partSize * divider) {
    partSize++;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < divider; i++) {
    final start = i * partSize;
    if (start >= length) {
      break;
    }

    var end = start + partSize;
    if (end > length) {
      end = length;
    }

    yield data.sublist(start, end);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
3 workers: ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16])
=====
data: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
4 workers: ([3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11], [12, 13])
=====
data: [7, 8, 3, 4]
8 workers: ([7], [8], [3], [4])
```

Comment: I have checked your code it crush it it run as follow: https://gist.github.com/bubnenkoff/43908b7d3a4864f9835f27d4f9ac0b25 `RangeError (RangeError (start): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..12: 14)`

Comment: @DmitryBubnenkov Thank you (and sorry). Now it works (after some corrections). I means second option. You can try again.